# Locating Peak from current bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I would like to locate the Peak Bar from current bar. This series are as much as 100 bars

```
H1=  high[2]>high[0] and high[2]>=high[1] and high[2]>high[3] and high[2]>high[4]?1:0
H2=  high[3]>high[1] and high[3]>=high[2] and high[3]>high[4] and high[3]>high[5]?2:0
H3=  high[4]>high[2] and high[4]>=high[3] and high[4]>high[5] and high[4]>high[6]?3:0
H4=  high[5]>high[3] and high[5]>=high[4] and high[5]>high[6] and high[5]>high[7]?4:0
H5=  high[6]>high[4] and high[6]>=high[5] and high[6]>high[7] and high[6]>high[8]?5:0
 ........

H96=high[97]>high[95] and high[97]=>high[96] and high[97]>high[98] and high[97]>high[99]?96:0
H97=high[98]>high[96] and high[98]=>high[97] and high[98]>high[99] and high[98]>high[100]?97:0
H98=high[99]>high[97] and high[99]=>high[98] and high[99]>high[100] and high[99]>high[101]?98:0
H99=high[100]>high[98] and high[100]=>high[99] and high[100]>high[101] and high[100]>high[102]?99:0
```

It can't make it. The script calculates the current bar but also keeps re-calculating the previous bar and 3rd last bars in series  ... Eventually, I cannot locate the Peak Bar.

I know finding Peak is easy.

```
H1=  high[2]>high[0] and high[2]>=high[1] and high[2]>high[3] and high[2]>high[4]?1:0
```

Then use plot function to offset -2 and label it with "P".

However, addressing the Peak from current bar is very difficult. Could someone offer me a help please?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you out?

```
//@version=5
indicator('Swing Hi/Lo', overlay=true)

var int  barsback = input.int(3, 'Bars back to check for a swing', 0)

swing_high = ta.pivothigh(barsback, barsback)
swing_low  = ta.pivotlow(barsback, barsback)

plotshape(swing_high, style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red,   offset=-barsback)
plotshape(swing_low,  style=shape.arrowup,   location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, offset=-barsback)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I wanna locate the Peak with series number (H1, H2, H3) and tough with number sequence (L1, L2 and L3). My original intention to spot out the high/low shift (ie previous supports becoming latest resistance or vice versa.)

https://www.tradingview.com/x/fjp3XNZV/

I will use H1-L2 = around zero or H1-L3 = around zero to work that out.
Your scripts with subtracting pivothigh and  pivotlow [2] with offset didn’t work in this way.
Any clues that can help to spot that out please? Thanks for review